# Text Field Validation With REGEX and Proper Error Message In Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**At First, my question may seems as a duplicate one to you, but surely not, I will explain why, because all the stack overflow answer regarding name validation, text field validation explain about validation with a message only...!**

My requirement is different that in my validation check I need to allow only characters(Using REGEX), and if anything else entered, error must be displayed. How can I achieve it ?

**Please dont report it as duplicate as I will get blocked** with next false reporting..... if you stil find it as a duplicate question please comment me the link that I have not yet seen in comment box, then I will delete my question, anyhow I dont need to get locked in using stack overflow... :(

Comment: You need to understand that we don't mark questions as duplicates out of spite. There are many questions which cover this exact topic - if you don't understand a given question than start with that question and ask about the parts you don't understand. Telling us not to moderate will only get you downvoted and your question closed anyways.

Comment: PS. Finding the answer is pretty trivial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |thing|
    errors.add_to_base("Custom error message") unless thing.my_attribute =~ /THING_REGEX/
  end
end
```